# New to excel and need some help to copy data to a new sheet and keep it going

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and not sure how I need to go about doing what I want. I am trying to collect certain data from one sheet(Receive Tracker) to another sheet(data) and than clear the contents of my Receiver Tracker Sheet. How do I keep the data and not overwrite? Also sometimes data will need to go beyond A:16-D:16 on the Receive Tracker what's the best way to go about just pulling everything from A:6-D:6 and below?

```
Sub CopyPasteClear()
'
' CopyPasteClear Macro
'

'
    Range("A6:D16").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("data").Select
    Range("A:A").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Recieve Tracker").Select
    Range("B6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("D6").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A8:D16").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("G12").Select
End Sub
```

******EDIT
I tried to edit the code as follows but still not getting the result I want
    Sub CopyPasteClear()
    '
    ' CopyPasteClear Macro
    '

```
'
Range("A6:D1000").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("data").Select
lastrow = Sheets("data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A:A").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("data").Range("A" & lastrow)

Sheets("Recieve Tracker").Select
Range("B6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
Range("D6").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A8:D16").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("G12").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to edit the code as follows but still not getting the result I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Copy Paste Clear

### Links

[Workbook Download (Dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdtdq2cvrrkdvpw/new-to-excel-and-need-some-help-to-copy-data-to-a-new-sheet-and-keep-it-going_54317440.xls?dl=0)

### The Code

```
Sub CopyPasteClear()

    'Source
    Const cSource As String = "Recieve Tracker"   ' Worksheet Name
    Const cFirstRsrc As Long = 6                  ' First Row Number
    Const cClr As String = "B6,D6"                ' Clear Cells
    Const cRowClr As Long = 8                     ' First Clear Row
    Const cFinal As String = "G12"                ' Final Select Cell Address
    ' Target
    Const cTarget As String = "Data"              ' Worksheet Name
    ' Both
    Const cCol1 As Variant = "A"                  ' First Column Letter/Number
    Const cCol2 As Variant = "D"                  ' Second Column Letter/Number

    Dim vntVal As Variant   ' Value Array
    Dim LastRsrc As Long    ' Source Last Row Number
    Dim LastRtgt As Long    ' Target Last Row Number

    ' Source Range into Source Array
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSource)
        ' Calculate Source Last Row Number of First Column.
        LastRsrc = .Columns(cCol1).Find("*", , -4123, , 2, 2).Row
        ' Prevent copying data above First Row. Rows from First Row to
        ' one less than First Clear Row will still be copied. To prevent this,
        ' change cFirstRsrc to cRowClr in the following line only.
        If LastRsrc < cFirstRsrc Then Exit Sub
        ' Copy Source Range into Source Array
        vntVal = .Range(.Cells(cFirstRsrc, cCol1), .Cells(LastRsrc, cCol2))
    End With

    ' Source Array into Target Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget)
        ' Check if First Column in Target Worksheet does contain a value.
        If Not .Columns(cCol1).Find("*", .Cells(.Rows.Count, _
                .Columns.Count), -4123, , 2) Is Nothing Then ' Found.
            ' Calculate Target Last Row Number of First Column.
            LastRtgt = .Columns(cCol1).Find("*", , -4123, , 2, 2).Row
          Else  ' Not found.
            LastRtgt = 0 ' Because 1 will be added in the next line of the code.
        End If
        ' Copy Source Array into Target Range. Note that Target Last Row
        ' Number has to be inreased by 1 to get the first empty row.
        .Cells(LastRtgt + 1, cCol1) _
                .Resize(UBound(vntVal), UBound(vntVal, 2)) = vntVal
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSource)
        ' Prevent deleting data above First Clear Row.
        If LastRsrc < cRowClr Then Exit Sub
        ' Clear contents of Clear Cells and modified Source Range.
        Union(.Range(cClr), .Range(.Cells(cRowClr, cCol1), _
                .Cells(LastRsrc, cCol2))).ClearContents
        ' Activate Source Worksheet if it is not active (not the ActiveSheet).
        ' The following Select method will produce an error if the program
        ' was started while a different worksheet than the Source Worksheet
        ' was active.
        If .Parent.ActiveSheet.Name <> .Name Then
            .Activate
        End If
        ' Select Final Select Cell.
        .Range(cFinal).Select
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks VBasic. It took me a few mins to get it to run without a runtime error. I had to have data in A1 on my data sheet so I just put the title of the sheet on there as a header and it all worked out apricate the help from you both!

Comment: @Scott: Many thanks for the feedback. It is a true mistake of mine. I'm sorry for the inconvenience. The error must have occurred in the line **LastRtgt = .Columns(cCol1).Find("*", , -4123, , 2, 2).Row**, where the row could not have been calculated because the range was **Nothing** due to no data in column A. I wrongly assumed that you would have headers in Target Worksheet. I'll fix it ASAP. You should download my workbook which contains a nice functionality with buttons so you could practically see what  my assumptions were.

Comment: @Scott: Added the **If Not...End If code block**. Now you can have a **blank worksheet** as the Target Worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

This will cut the data from the Receive Tracker (A6:D6 and down) and paste it into the Data at the bottom (appending data to the bottom). **It does not rely on data being in A1**

```
Sub CopyPasteClear()
Dim cutRange As Range, pasteRange As Range
Dim shData As Worksheet
Dim shReceive As Worksheet

'You can adjust the names of the worksheets
'here, if needed
Set shData = Worksheets("Data")
Set shReceive = Worksheets("Receive Tracker")

'get the ranges we need to cut and paste
Set cutRange = shReceive.Range("A6:D" & shReceive.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 6)
Set pasteRange = shData.UsedRange.Cells(shData.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(cutRange.Rows.Count, cutRange.Columns.Count)

'cut and paste
cutRange.Cut pasteRange
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get a runtime error "PasteSpecial Method of range class failed". I have a formula in the (data)sheet on different columns could that affect it? they are in columns G,H, and I

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed the answer. Looks like Excel didn't want to paste it to a specific range, so this will first select the range, then use the built-in paste function.